# ActiveControl.Name sometimes returns empty string

Tags: winforms

I have a main winform that hosts a UserControl.  The user control hosts various other controls including textboxes, buttons and a grid.  I have been using UserControl.ActiveControl.Name to determine the name of the currently active control.  This mostly works well.

However, at times, I get the empty string instead of the actual control name.  My grid has 1 editable column and my feeling is that it is tied to that somehow.  I mean, when I am in editmode, I get the empty string for activecontrol name even though the grid is the active control.  Why?

Using: VS2012, .NET 4.0

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a DataGridView; When you are in edit mode there is a control added that has no name.  So the name is blank, but the control is not null, so there is a valid control there.  If you look at the `AccessibleName` property on the control, you will see the value of "Editing Control".

Comment: OK, I checked this out and you are on the button.  Good stuff here.  And yes, it is a DataGridView and you also confirmed my assumption about this being tied to the edit control within the grid column.